# Удалить class в определённом случае

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть товары, в ряду по 3 товара. Мне нужно выполнить `$('.list .discount_price').remove()` у всех товаров ряда, у которого отсутствует `class="test"`.

Выходит, что `$('.list .discount_price').remove()`, нужно выполнить у товаров первого и третьего ряда.

Сам пока не смог придумать алгоритм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/obd5juec/2/

```css
.clearfix {display: block;}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {display: table; line-height: 0; content: '';}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}

.fl_l {float: left;}
.fl_r {float: right;}

.list {width: 250px}
.list .item {width: 70px}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      1
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      2
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      3
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      4
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price">
        <div class="test"></div>
      </div>
      5
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      6
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      7
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      8
    </div>
    
    <div class="fl_l item">
      <div class="discount_price"></div>
      9
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в ряду только 3 элемента?

Comment: @Grundy, да, в ряду 3 элемента.

Comment: Всегда? или может меняться количество?

Comment: @Grundy, всегда. Оно не будет меняться вообще. Строго 3 элемента в ряду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не бейте сапогами за солянку:

```js
$(function() {
  //массив рядков
  var rowsArr = [];
  //колво рядков
  var numRows = $('.discount_price').length / 3;
  //$-массив
  var d = $('.discount_price');
  //счетчик элементов-товаров
  var k = 0;

  //формируем двумерный масив рядков-строк
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    rowsArr[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      rowsArr[i][j] = d.eq(k);
      k++;
    }
  }

  //перебор рядков
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsArr.length; i++) {
    var flagRow = rowsArr[i].some(function(el) {
      if (el.has('.test').length) {
        return true;
      }
    });

    if (!flagRow) {
      rowsArr[i].map(function(el, i) {
        el.parent().remove();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.clearfix {
  display: block;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: '';
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.fl_l {
  float: left;
}
.fl_r {
  float: right;
}
.list {
  width: 250px
}
.list .item {
  width: 70px
}
.discount_price {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class="list">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        1
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        2
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        3
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        4
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price">
          <div class="test"></div>
        </div>
        5
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        6
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        7
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        8
      </div>

      <div class="fl_l item">
        <div class="discount_price"></div>
        9
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, конечно ряды скрывать не надо было, но тут я уже сам подправлю под себя)